# Отправка ответа на POST запрос на android устройство

Tags: post, php, клиент-сервер, android, сервер

Добрый вечер, пишу программу которая должна отправлять POST запрос на сервер, сервер же проводит с полученными данными сервера определенные действия, а после них отправляет ответ на запрос:

```
if ($n==3) // Удаление существующей записи
    {
    $query_delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";
    $res_delete = mysql_query ($query_delete, $link);
    if ($res_delete ) echo ("Запись удалена");
    }
```

Но в результате тестов в ответ приходит вся страница + разнообразные Notice от php так как на странице кроме этой обработке запроса есть еще две, в общем обработка запросов выглядит так:

```
if (isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['id']))// && и тд) { //исправленна обработка поста и его его парамметров Г //начало изменений
{
    $v = $_POST['v'];
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pn = $_POST['pn'];
    $dt = $_POST['dt'];
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $st = $_POST['st'];

    if ($n==1) // Добавление новой записи
    {
    $query_log = "INSERT into Log values('$id','','$dt','','','$x','$y','$st')";
    $query = "INSERT into Users values('$id','$name','$pn','$dt','$x','$y','','$st')";
    // ID, имя, номер телефона, время, широта, долгота, статус
    $res = mysql_query($query, $link);
    $res_log = mysql_query($query_log, $link);
    if ($res) echo ("<br/>"."Запись добавлена");
    }

    if ($n==2) // Изменение существующей записи
    {
    $query_log = "INSERT into Log values('$id','','$dt','','','$x','$y','$st')";
    #SELECT (`ID`, `Name`, `LatitudeX` , `LongitudeY`) FROM Users  WHERE ID LIKE '$id' ";
    #$query_log2 = "UPDATE Log SET DateTime='$dt', NewLatitudeX='$x', NewLongitudeY='$y' WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";  
    $query_update = "UPDATE Users SET DateTime='$dt', LatitudeX='$x', LongitudeY='$y', Status='$st' WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";   
    $res_log = mysql_query($query_log, $link);  
    #$res_log2 = mysql_query($query_log2, $link);   
    $res_update = mysql_query($query_update, $link);    
    #if ($res_update) echo ("<br/>"."Запись обновлена");
    }

    if ($n==3) // Удаление существующей записи
    {
    $query_delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";
    $res_delete = mysql_query ($query_delete, $link);
    //if ($res_delete ) 
    echo ("Запись удалена");
    }
  }  
  else 
  {

  }
```

Пожалуйста помогите, подскажите какие изменения надо сделать чтобы на запрос приходил только нудный ответ. 
П.С. есть конечно вариант для каждого запроса создать свою страницу, но для меня это не выход необходимо чтобы все было в одном месте.
    Заранее Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может раз у вас такая структура, то лучше switch использовать?

```
<?php
// Начало файла, перед всем выводом
if (isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    // ...
    switch ($n) {
        case 1:
            $query_log = '...';
            $query = '...';
            $message = 'Запись добавлена';
            break;
        case 2:
            $query_log = '...';
            $query = '...';
            $message = 'Запись изменена';
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            // ...
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_query($query_log, $link)) {
            echo 'Ошибка базы данных: логи не записаны';
        }
        echo $message;
    } else {
        echo 'Ошибка базы данных';
    }
    exit(); // Если заданы $_POST, то код завершит работу в этом месте.
}
// Тут идет разметка страницы. Вывод ваших таблиц, ссылок и проч.
?>
```

Comment: Отвечаю по породяку.
1. с андройд устройства отправляются запросы и он должен получить ответ.
2. нотисы что переменные не определены.

В начале страницы есть несколько ссылок на другие страницы 
<a href  ....>
плюс ниже расположена таблица вывода таблицы из БД.
и при получении ответа на запрос в нем пишутся еще эти ссылки и код таблицы.

Comment: А на PC все нормально, не пустое приходит?

Вы бы тогда код с андроида показали. Если значения не отправляются - дело в клиенте.

Comment: если тестить с ПК GET запросами через браузер, то приходят ссылки текст + ответ на запрос.
вот моя первоначальная проблема
http://hashcode.ru/questions/119918/проблема-с-получением-ответа-на-post-запрос

Comment: Если на ПК наботает, то проблема, очевидно, в клиенте андройда

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло)